# APScheduler not starting?

Tags: python, scheduler

I would like to run a python script during the night and so I was thinking of using APScheduler. I'll start running it at 1am of the following night and it will run once every night

my scheduler script looks like this (scheduler.py):

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time, date

def myScript():
    print "ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = Scheduler()
    startDate = datetime.combine(date.today() + timedelta(days=1),time(1))
    sched.start()
    sched.add_interval_job(myScript, start_date = startDate, days=1)
```

In the shell, I do:
`python myScheduler.py & disown` (I'm running it remotely, so I want to run it in the background and disown it. 
Immediately, a number (PID) appears below the line, as every other python script would do. But when I do ps -e | grep python, that number is not there. I tried to do `kill -9 PID` and I got a message saying that the job does not exist.

Is the scheduler running? If yes, how can I stop it? if not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you have to keep the script running otherwise after the `sched.add_interval_job(myScript, start_date = startDate, days=1)`, the script ends and stop.
add a

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(10)
sched.shutdown()
```

after, and then, the scheduler will still be alive.

Comment: Why do you need sched.shutdown()? Will it ever get hit?

Comment: @cssndrx : if you launch the application in a console (without the &), you will be able to stop it by pressing Ctrl + C, then in this case the `sched.shutdown()` will be reached

Comment: @CédricJulien Oh neat! Why is that?

Answer (score 9):

The correct solution would be to tell the scheduler to not run as a daemon:

```
sched = Scheduler()
sched.daemonic = False
```

or

```
sched = Scheduler()
sched.configure({'apscheduler.daemonic': False})
```

Comment: I like this solution, but it becomes impossible to kill the process without a `sudo kill pid`, any suggestions?

Comment: In the latest version of apscheduler, it is `daemon` not `daemonic`. `scheduler.configure({'apscheduler.daemon': False})` is worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I have apscheduler v3 installed and this is what I would do.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler  
def mainjob():
    print("It works!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_job(mainjob, 'interval', seconds=120)
    input("Press enter to exit.")
    sched.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 3):

here is my way:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
def mainjob():
    print("It works!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = Scheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_interval_job(mainjob,minutes=1)
    input("Press enter to exit.")
    sched.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use version 2.1.0, you can also pass standalone=True parameter to the Scheduler constructor. Detail documents can be found [here](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time, date

def myScript():
    print "ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = Scheduler(standalone=True)
    startDate = datetime.combine(date.today() + timedelta(days=1),time(1))
    sched.add_interval_job(myScript, start_date = startDate, days=1)
    sched.start()
```

Comment: But for a standalone service to run it should have a job that never ends. Otherwise scheduler will end execution. And moreover it blocks your main thread and it actually becomes a pain when you are adding additional jobs after starting the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [blocking scheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler) nowadays.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
# scheduler.add_job(...)
scheduler.add_interval_job(myScript, start_date = startDate, days=1)
scheduler.start()
```