# Running apschduler in Python script as a daemon?

Tags: python

I have a `job.py` which has the following code.

```
import datetime
import logging
import sys
import os

from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler
from src.extractors.pExtractor import somejob

def run_job():
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    logging.debug('Proposal extraction job starting')
    somejob.main()
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    duration = end - start
    logging.debug('job completed , took ' + str(duration.seconds) + ' seconds')

def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/pExtractor.log', level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(levelname)s[%(asctime)s]: %(message)s')
    sched = Scheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_interval_job(run_job, minutes=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- When I run this on the command prompt, it exits immediately:

> INFO[2012-04-03 13:31:02,825]: Started thread pool with 0 core threads
>   and 20 maximum threads INFO[2012-04-03 13:31:02,827]: Scheduler
>   started INFO[2012-04-03 13:31:02,827]: Added job "run_job (trigger:
>   cron[minute='2'], next run at: 2012-04-03 14:02:00)" to job store
>   "default" INFO[2012-04-03 13:31:02,828]: Shutting down thread pool

- How can I makde this run as a daemon?

Comment: The resoulution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835600/apscheduler-not-starting

Answer (score 0):

Write your `main()` as below.

```
def main():
    [... your_code_as_in_your_question ...]
    while (True):
        pass
```

Additionally it shouldn't hurt to consider [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/).